# Draw a line to show the device motion

Tags: ios, iphone, gyroscope, core-motion

I want to track the motion of device along 0-180 degrees from left to right (up and downwards also) and show it on the device screen like a graph. I am using device motion sensors to draw the line but unable to find which values I need to use for.

```
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
 {
     CGFloat rotationRateY = motion.rotationRate.y;
     CGFloat rotationRateX = motion.rotationRate.x;

     if (fabs(rotationRateY) >= 0.1f || fabs(rotationRateX) >= 0.1f)
     {
         CMAttitude *currentAttitude = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude;

         newXVal = (int)round(degrees(currentAttitude.roll));
         newYVal = (int)round(degrees(currentAttitude.pitch));
         newZVal = (int)round(degrees(currentAttitude.yaw));

         // Degrees should always be positive
         if(newZVal < 0)
         {
             newZVal = newZVal + 360;
         }
         else
         {
             newZVal = newZVal + 180;
         }

         //I want to track some cgpoints to draw the line here I think but how...:(
     }
 }];
```

In the above code I am depending on yaw value to track 0 - 180 degrees but it is changing as I move the device up/down, so I couldn't use the values.

For Reference:[image]

Thanks.

Comment: did you found the answer ? Or can you please share how you sort out the thing

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing this is that the only information you get back from the device about movement is acceleration. (i.e. not position or speed).

You might be able to work out which direction the device is currently accelerating in. But not how far it has travelled (or how fast) in that direction.

Using this you could then put lines down.

i.e. right, up, right, down, right, diagonal up, diagonal down, right, etc...

You can get this from the `userAcceleration` property of `CMDeviceMotion`. This then has x, y, and z values.

There are many resources about why it's hard (impossible) to work out location though... [This is one of the best I have found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q_8d0E3tDk). It's the same reason that the Oculus Rift 2 has an external camera to track movement.

Good luck though :)

Comment: I think Panorama uses some mechanism to track the device motion (Like start at a point and ends at a point, alerts user about move down/up). Do you have any idea how it is working?

Comment: @Gani414 Panorama will use the rotation of the device. i.e. the compass direction. Notice that you can create a panorama by holding the device perfect still and rotating it. Equally, if you move the phone without rotating the panorama won't move. For this you can use `magneticField` property or `rotationRate` property to get just the rotation.

Comment: @Gani414 also, the camera can be used as a way of having an external point of reference to track motion. It doesn't just rely on the device.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks for the quick reply. Actually I am trying to draw the line as in the image. In my case user moves the device same like taking panorama picture as Gani414 mentioned. Here I am not getting how to use the rotation rate to get tracking points to draw the line, I think it gives the rotation rate around X, Y and Z axis.

Comment: @Gani414 oh I see. What's the actual problem you're having then? Not really certain what is/isn't working.

Comment: @Fogmeister I have an external point lets say (0, 60), and I need to extend that point with the generated points from the properties x,y and z of rotationRate to draw a line. I didn't find way to generate the points from the rotaionRate.